# Is it possible to force an update of an Interface?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

In resharper is it possible to force an update of an interface?

Basically I have a class that inherits from an interface but this class is constantly changing so I need to reflect the changes in the interface otherwise VS complains that I am not implementing something as the signature of the method has changed.

I was wondering if there is a way in resharper to say "Update this class with its interface" ?

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you should try to stabilize your way of working with this, the fact that the interface is mapped after the class, and that they change a lot, sounds to me as though you don't have a clear specification of what you need to build.

Comment: Thanks everyone, yes i was actually designing the class as i go .. its the wrong direction. Should evaluate first..

Comment: What if you are doing TDD and need the interfaces for mocking, etc. Wouldn't this be a scenario where the interface is changing with the implementation?

Comment: @mark Agreed I have the same problem, did you find a solution, I do TDD this way too

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Letting the interface follow the implementation is the exact wrong direction. First, you should define in your interface, what you need, then implement it in the backing class. You shouldn't expect a tool to support undesired workflows instead...

If you go the right way, R# will give you all support you ever need: You can refactor existing methods via *Refactor|Rename...*, *Refactor|Change Signature...* and *Implement Members*.

Comment: I agree if you are developing a new thing. However, if you are refactoring a legacy system and trying to write some unit tests, then the workflow works upside-down. For example, I extracted the interface but then noticed the static members. Removed the static keyword and needed to update the interface as well.

Comment: This response doesn't answer the question - regardless if the workflow is good or bad.

Answer (score 29):

Although not the best way to design, sometimes it is necessary to update the interface based on the modified class.

You **can** update the interface using resharper's **Pull Members Up** option.

1. Use the `Pull Members Up` option in the refactor menu
2. Select the interface you would like to update as the base type
3. Select the members you would like to add to the interface

The members have now been added to the interface.

Comment: Just be alert that if you have XML comments on existing methods, this will blow those away--but you can copy the replaced methods, undo, paste them in below, and delete the duplicates (easily found by R#'s highlighting the duplicates).

Comment: Is not there any way these days without resharper? (just using VS2017)

Answer (score 2):

If you use ReSharper to modify the method, it can/will also modify the interface definition.

For instance, if you use ReSharper's [Rename](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Rename) functionality on the method, the interface definition of it will get renamed. Additionally, if you use ReSharper's [Change Signature](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html#Change_Signature) functionality on the method, it asks you if you want to do the refactoring on the interface as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're changing signature of a method defined in an interface, change it via *Refactor* - *Change Signature...*. ReSharper will then ask you if you want to change signature of an interface method.

Other than that, I cannot imagine how would ReShaper know what and how to update.